# How to cache script returned via PHP

Tags: php, web, browser, webserver, browser-cache

I need to return script to user if he is accepted. It is too long to check user, and i want return 304 Not modified. I have simple code to check, but it don't work. Browser do not resquest If-Modified-Since. If it were source *.js extentsion, it could be script.js?ver=1.0 for example? but not with *.php
Is this way write or there is another one?

html code:

```
<script src="get_secret_script.php"></script>
```

php code:

```
$script_name = "./script.js";
$last_modified = filemtime($script_name);
$etag = hash_file('crc32b', $script_name);
header("Content-Type: text/javascript");

//header("Etag: $etag");

// Condition not met, there is no $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']
// in browser request
if(@strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) == $last_modified)
{
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", $last_modified) . " GMT", true, 304);  
    exit;
}

$fp = fopen($script_name, 'r'); 
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", $last_modified) . " GMT", true, 200);
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($script_name));

fpassthru($fp); 
exit;
```

Browser request (not first):

```
GET /test/get_secret_script.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Browser identity string
Accept: */*
Referer: http://127.0.0.1/test/test.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your case, i think you can apply some rewrite rule in htaccess or server configuration:
For example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase  /
    RewriteRule ^script.js get_secret_script.php[NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: In get_secret_script.php i need to check if this user have access to this script. If i will write this, it returns script to all users. Right?

Comment: No, the rewrite rule just simple change the url.
for example:
^script.js get_secret_script.php[NC,L]
when it meet the request script.js, it will process the get_secret_script.php. 
You can test and debug some rewrite rule and see the results.

Comment: And if want to save params like secret.js?123456 -> get_secret_script.php?id=123456?

Comment: All parameters will be forwarded with same name also.
I think you should change the parameter in the js file:
secret.js?ver=12345

So in the php, you can also retrieve this parameter and do your business or alternatively you can customize the rewrite rule.